# Call a function after 2 changes are detected

Tags: angular

This is my code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-team-seaon-kit',
  templateUrl: './team-seaon-kit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./team-seaon-kit.component.css']
})


export class TeamSeaonKitComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() colorKit;
  @Input() seasonKitOptions;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if(changes.colorKit && changes.colorKit.currentValue !== undefined && changes.seasonKitOptions && changes.seasonKitOptions.currentValue !== undefined){
      this.updateCheckedSeasonKitRadioButton();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to call function `updateCheckedSeasonKitRadioButton()` once I have the value of `colorKit` and the one of `seasonKitOptions`

The problem is that these two values are not bound to this component simultaneously so the condition inside of my If statement is never verified.

This is how I bind these two values from parent component to child component:

```
<app-team-seaon-kit  [(colorKit)]="homeColorKit" [seasonKitOptions]="homeTeamJersey.seasonKitOptions" [team]="homeTeamJersey"></app-team-seaon-kit>

<app-team-seaon-kit [(colorKit)]="awayColorKit" [seasonKitOptions]="awayTeamJersey.seasonKitOptions" [team]="awayTeamJersey"></app-team-seaon-kit>
```

I guess that one way to make this work would be to bind the two variables in one object, which would look like this:

```
<app-team-seaon-kit [(colorKit)]="'colorKit':awayColorKit,'seasonKit':awayTeamJersey.seasonKitOptions" [team]="awayTeamJersey"></app-team-seaon-kit>
```

But this is not my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just check if both of those values exist upon change detection?

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if(this.colorKit && this.seasonKitOptions) {
      this.updateCheckedSeasonKitRadioButton();
    }
  }
```

Considering your use case, you have to check your input variables directly, and not depend on `ngOnChanges` parameter `changes` as it returns every change on its own.